# Different ways of handling exceptions in Jetty/Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jetty, scalatra

Short version of the question: What would cause Scalatra/(Jetty or Tomcat) to pass the execution to *handle* of an ErrorHandler without setting the request attribute "javax.servlet.error.exception"?

Longer one with more context: In a project that I've joined recently the ErrorHandlers' handle method has separate blocks for handling exceptions from "javax.servlet.error.exception" request attribute and all other exceptions. We run our application in Jetty and as I understand Jetty unwraps ServletExceptions and puts them in the attribute above. What would cause the block handling the non "javax.servlet.error.exception" exceptions to be called then? Or is it redundant and can be removed?

The person that originally wrote the code left the project. The rest of the tech-stack is Scala and Scalatra, if it makes any difference.

```
  Option(request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception"))
  .map { 
    exception => exception match {
         //various exceptions handled
   }.getOrElse(handleStatusCode(currentStatus))
```

**EDIT**: it seems that in certain environments the code runs on Tomcat.

Comment: Please add the code you have now.

Comment: "What would cause the other block to be called then?" Other block?

Comment: updated the question to provide more information

Answer (score 0):

There are several method calls happening in this block of code, which is equivalent to the following:

```
val a = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception")
val b = Option(a)
val c = b.map { exception => /* various exceptions handled... */ }
val d = c.getOrElse(handleStatusCode(currentStatus))
```

So, `a` is just a plain Java call.  It will look up the specified attribute on the request, and will return either the `Object` that was mapped to that attribute, or `null`.

For `b` we call the `Option` constructor to wrap the previous result up in an Option (this is more Scala-esque than dealing with nulls).  So if `a` was `null` then `b` will be `None`, otherwise it will be a `Some` instance containing the (non-null) value of `a`.

On the next line, this Option is mapped into a new value.  If `b` was `None` (i.e. `a` was `null`) then `c` will also be `None`.  Otherwise, the logic within the braces is applied to the value contained within `b`, and this result is returned wrapped in a `Some`.

Finally, the Option is unwrapped.  If `c` contained some value, then this value itself is the result of the whole block.  Otherwise, is `c` was `None`, then `handleStatusCode(currentStatus)` is evaluated, and its result is the result of the whole block.

---

Therefore, we can say that `handleStatusCode` will be called if and only if `c` is `None` => `b` was `None` => `a` was `null` => the request had no attribute mapped to `"javax.servlet.error.exception"`.

This should usually be the case (e.g. on every non-error request).  As such it would only be safe to remove the code if this block appears within a check such as:

```
if (request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception") != null) {
   ...
   // your posted code
}
```

Even if you were to remove it, what would you replace it with?  What should be the result when the `Option` is empty?  Calling `get()` on an Option is generally a bad idea for this reason; and if you *know* it's never empty, you don't need to wrap it as per line `b` above.

Comment: It's not what question was about. Sorry if I was still unclear. I understand Scala code and the question is about Jetty/Scalatra/servlet integration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the full context, but I could imagine the following scenario.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ErrorPageServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlet/errorPage/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
  <!--unauthorized-->
  <error-code>401</error-code>
  <location>/servlet/errorPage/401</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
  <!--internal server error-->
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/servlet/errorPage/500</location>
</error-page>
```

Above basically says "use the same ErrorPageServlet" for different types of HTTP errors.

Then in the servlet, you have a conditional to check if there was an uncaught exception (looking at `"javax.servlet.error.exception"` request attribute) or if there was none, maybe there was something that caused HTTP 401.